# Duplicator live to wamp https to http

Tags: plugins, database, migration, https, http

sorry for my english... 
So I want to get my data from a https live site back to localhost. Using duplicator plugin works fine exept that I run (especially in Chrome) to a problem with absolute setted image links, wich refer to https://localhost ... .

I wonder if someone is out there who knows a solution for this issue.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to edit your `wp-config.php` and add the lines:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com/');
```

with https or http.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. Firefox is fine chrome still not showing the https images but throws an "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR". Anyway many thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems you have browser cache. Try to load your site via chrome incognito mode

Comment: Wow. This does the trick for me. Saved me hours... Thank U so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

So either set up 301 redirects for the local site or use a plugin such as velvet blues